# Строим месячные графики цены

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, matplotlib

Как построить по колонке Open график цен с января по декабрь, наложенных друг на друге за несколько лет на одном графике?

Строим по файлам взятых из одной папки и потом сохраним в виде графиков, с названием файла от куда были взяты данные.

```css
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as wb
mport matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

a = r'C:/Users/II/Downloads/*.csv' 

files = glob.glob(a)

for f in files:
    a = pd.read_csv(f, index_col='Date', encoding='latin1', parse_dates=['Date'])
   
#

    res.plot.bar(rot=0)
    pic_fn = os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + pic_ext
    plt.savefig(pic_fn)
```

Данные

```js
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
2007-01-03,86.290001,97.800003,81.900002,85.729996,350823100.0,11.107141
2007-02-01,86.229996,90.810005,82.860001,84.610001,192655600.0,10.962033
2007-03-01,84.029999,96.83000200000001,83.75,92.90999599999999,187718200.0,12.037377000000001
2007-04-02,94.139999,102.5,89.599998,99.800003,175953100.0,12.930043
2007-05-01,99.59000400000001,122.170006,98.550003,121.189995,212069700.0,15.701322
2007-06-01,121.09999099999999,127.610001,115.39999399999999,122.040001,290683100.0,15.811448
2007-07-02,121.049995,148.919998,119.299995,131.759995,306916200.0,17.070766
2007-08-01,133.639999,139.650009,111.61999499999999,138.48001100000002,274322600.0,17.941408
2007-09-04,139.940002,155.0,130.0,153.470001,283504200.0,19.883505
2007-10-01,154.630005,190.119995,152.93000800000002,189.949997,262077200.0,24.609837
2007-11-01,188.600006,192.68000800000002,150.630005,182.220001,326042700.0,23.608341
2007-12-03,181.860001,202.959991,176.990005,198.07998700000002,222400100.0,25.663155
2008-01-02,199.26998899999998,200.26001000000002,126.139999,135.360001,434756700.0,17.53718
2008-02-01,136.23998999999998,136.58999599999999,115.440002,125.020004,326517900.0,16.197536
2008-03-03,124.440002,145.73998999999998,118.0,143.5,296191700.0,18.591795
2008-04-01,146.300003,180.0,143.610001,173.949997,271892100.0,22.536884
```

Comment: Пока не совсем понятно что вы хотите отобразить на графике... Какие данные в файлах - разбивка по месяцам или по фирмам, но за весь временной период? Данные в файлах за один год?

Comment: Вы можете выложить запаковать ваши файлы в один архив (.zip, 7z, .tar.gz) и выложить на какой-нибудь файлообменник без регистрации, чтобы не генерировать ?

Comment: да, на плюсах это наверное потяжелее будет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для построения линейных графиков лучше всего преобразовать данные из длинного в широкий формат (PIVOT):

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as wb
#import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')


def plot_graph(filename, pic_ext='.jpg'):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
    plt.figure()
    r = df[['Open']].assign(year=df.index.year, month=df.index.month) \
                    .pivot_table(index='month', columns='year',
                                 values='Open', aggfunc='mean')
    r.plot(legend=True, figsize=(16, 10))  # set legend=False to hide the legend
    #r.plot.area(legend=True, figsize=(16, 10))  # set legend=False to hide the legend
    plt.savefig(os.path.splitext(f)[0] + pic_ext)
    plt.close()


for f in glob.glob(r'D:\temp\.data\628603\*.csv'):
    plot_graph(f)
```

PS рекомендую ознакомиться с [примерами визуализации в Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html)

Результат:

```
D:\temp\.data\628603\AAON_data.jpg
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
D:\temp\.data\628603\AAPL_data.jpg
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
D:\temp\.data\628603\AAP_data.jpg
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться [seaborn.barplot](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html):

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as wb
import seaborn as sns

#import matplotlib
#matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

def plot_graph(filename, pic_ext='.jpg'):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
    r = df.assign(year=df.index.year, month=df.index.month)
    sns.barplot(data=r, x='month', y='Open', hue='year')
    plt.savefig(os.path.splitext(f)[0] + pic_ext)
    plt.clf()

for f in glob.glob(r'D:\temp\.data\628603\*.csv'):
    plot_graph(f)
```

Результат:

```
D:\temp\.data\628603\AAON_data.jpg
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
D:\temp\.data\628603\AAPL_data.jpg
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
D:\temp\.data\628603\AAP_data.jpg
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]